# Ассемблер: выделение памяти, DB

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Подскажите, пожалуйства, что делает это строка, написанная на языке Ассемблера?

```
db 65535 - 2 dup (0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387492/what-does-the-assembly-instruction-db-actually-do

Comment: Помещает в исполняемый файл 65533 нулевых байта.

Comment: dup это дубликаты. Дословно: Сделать 65535 - 2 дубликата ноля (который в скобках). (Можно делать дубликаты не только нуля, часто так же используется 0FFh)

Comment: Разве нету справочника по ассемблеру? Он, кстати, самый маленький.

Comment: маленький, да удаленький

Comment: с dup все было понятно. выражение смутило